# Union of function images

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that $$ f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{j\in J} B_j \right) = \bigcup_{j\in J}\; f^{-1}(B_j)$$

My first attempt is to use a direct sort of proof where I try to rewrite things using set builder notation.

Let $$x \in f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{j\in J} B_j \right).$$ Then it follows that

$x \in \{x \in X : f(x) \in \bigcup_{j\in J} B_j\}$. Then it follows that $f(x) \in \bigcup_{j\in J} B_j$. However, I do not know how to proceed from here or finish the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supose that $f(x) \in \bigcup_{j \in J}B_j$, then by the definition of union exists a $i \in J$ such that: $f(x) \in B_i$. Then you have that $x \in f^{-1}(B_i) \subset \bigcup_{j \in J} f^{-1}(B_j)$.

For the other inclusion you can use the same idea.